# Joining first n-1 arguments in macro

Tags: c++, macros, declaration

I need to write a macro that looks like the following

```
MACRO(one, name, "some string");
```

If the macro has n arguments, I need to be able to concatenate the first `n-1` arguments together with underscores.  For example the above invocation would expand to

```
std::string one_name{"some string"};
```

Similarly, if I had something like this

```
MACRO(one, two, name, "some string");
```

I should get

```
std::string one_two_name{"some string"};
```

Is this possible?

---

**Disclaimer**: I can't get out of using a macro for this one.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider making a tool which auto-generates the code you want from some simple input file? Or possibly reconsider the requirements, andalysis and design you have that seemingly forces you to do something like that?

Comment: You could look into [Boost.Preprocessor](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) for this.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you explained the problem that you're _actually_ trying to solve

Comment: @alterigel I am trying to append the variable names to each other and also check to see if the names correspond to the namespace order the variable is declared in.  For example, if the macro is in `namespace a::b`  I would want to declare a variable called `a_b_name` as part of the macro expansion and check to see if `::a::b::a_b_name` is valid (and `static_assert` on the validity)

Comment: Don't think it is, no.  What is the maximum value of `n`?

Comment: @PaulSanders Let's go with 5 as the maximum value of `n`, is it implementable with that constraint?

Comment: Not that I can think of, >1 == infinity, but, ... how about 5 macros, one for each number of parameters? After all, how deep are you going to nest those namespaces?  If that works for you, I'll make it an answer.

Comment: And it might be possible to have MACRO5 invoke MACRO4 and so on, I'm not sure, it's too early in the morning to think.

Comment: It is possible with C11 and variadic macros. But I don't think it can be done in C++. Is C++ hard requirement?

Comment: @bartop Variadic macros are supported from C++11 onwards I believe (unless they somehow behave differently there).  But I don't see how they would solve this problem.  Maybe my macro-fu is not working this morning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With hard-coded limit, you might do:

```
#define COUNT_N(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, N, ...)    N
#define COUNT(...)   COUNT_N(__VA_ARGS__, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
// Warning: COUNT() return 1 (as COUNT(A)) :-/

#define IDENTITY(N) N
#define APPLY(macro, ...) IDENTITY(macro(__VA_ARGS__))

#define F_1(_) static_assert(false, "Not enough argument")
#define F_2(a, s) std::string a = s;
#define F_3(a, b, s) std::string a ## _ ## b = s;
#define F_4(a, b, c, s) std::string a ## _ ## b ## _ ## c= s;
#define F_5(a, b, c, d, s) std::string a ## _ ## b ## _ ## c ## _ ## d= s;
#define F_6(a, b, c, d, e, s) std::string a ## _ ## b ## _ ## c ## _ ## d ## _ ## e = s;
#define F_7(a, b, c, d, e, f, s) std::string a ## _ ## b ## _ ## c ## _ ## d ## _ ## e ## _ ## f= s;
#define F_8(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, s) std::string a ## _ ## b ## _ ## c ## _ ## d ## _ ## e ## _ ## f ## _ ## g = s;

#define DISPATCH(N) F_ ## N

#define Macro(...) IDENTITY(APPLY(DISPATCH, COUNT(__VA_ARGS__)))(__VA_ARGS__)
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/wBUdUr)

Comment: Not bad, not bad at all.  [Can always add one more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel).